# Issue with Google Data API Client for Objective-C Sent and get valid video url

Tags: ios, ios7, youtube-api

There are several sample code are available with library Google Data API Client for Objective-C i.e how  to upload Youtube video but my problem here is that here i get youtube link from other server and my question is how to sent that youtube url to the above library and get valid url so that i pass that url to MPMovieController player.

Thank a lot in advance